# mongodb return collection as hashmap?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose.js.  Is there a way to return my resource collection of documents from this

```
[
    {_id:1, name:'resource1', value:1},
    {_id:2, name:'resource2', value:2},
    etc...
]
```

to this? either with a map reducer or is there a native way with mongo to do this?

```
{
    resource1:{name:'resource1', value:1},
    resource2:{name:'resource2', value:2},
}
```

I have a large list of documents and would make my life easier looping through and keying off instead of scanning.

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use your data as field's name?

Comment: because I have another list from another api using the resource name. I can key off the resource name to get the new fields I need

Comment: The downside for doing so is that you will end up with a documents with dynamic field which are difficult to manipulate and **you will want to come back to the initial structure**.

Comment: true except I wont be saving the original document, just reading it.